# How to configure WebDriver with Arquillian using the Capabilities interface

Tags: webdriver, jboss-arquillian

I want to use Arquillian's Drone extension to configure WebDriver for some functional tests, using the Capabilities interface as described [here](http://planet.jboss.org/post/arquillian_drone_extension_1_1_0_cr1_released). I have added the artifacts arquillian-bom (version 1.0.2.Final), arquillian-drone-bom (version 1.1.0.CR2), arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain and arquillian-drone-webdriver as dependencies in my pom.xml, as shown below, and declared the capabilities as shown, but when I run my tests, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.<init>(DesiredCapabilities.java:51)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.configuration.TypedWebDriverConfiguration$5.invoke(TypedWebDriverConfiguration.java:268)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.configuration.TypedWebDriverConfiguration$5.invoke(TypedWebDriverConfiguration.java:259)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.configuration.TypedWebDriverConfiguration$CallInterceptor.intercept(TypedWebDriverConfiguration.java:65)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.configuration.TypedWebDriverConfiguration.getCapabilities(TypedWebDriverConfiguration.java:274)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.FirefoxDriverFactory.createInstance(FirefoxDriverFactory.java:79)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.FirefoxDriverFactory.createInstance(FirefoxDriverFactory.java:42)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.WebDriverFactory.createInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:129)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.WebDriverFactory.createInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneCreator.createWebTestBrowser(DroneCreator.java:71)
etc.
```

Looking at the code, I can see this NPE is caused by a class variable, capabilityMap, in TypedWebDriverConfiguration that is not being initialised.

What do I need to fix in the configuration to make this work?

pom.xml extract:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${drone.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${drone.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>${drone.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <extension qualifier="webdriver">
        <property name="browserCapabilities">firefox</property>
        <property name="capabilityWebdriverFirefoxBin">/usr/bin/firefox</property>
    </extension>
</arquillian>
```

WebDriver declaration in code:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class WebDriverTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        ...
    }

    @Drone
    WebDriver driver;   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a versioning problem caused by the dependency declarations in the Maven pom.xml. The Arquillian BOM artifacts need to be declared under dependencyManagement, with import scope. The pom.xml dependency declarations should look like this:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>${drone.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${drone.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>    
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Note that the arquillian-drone-webdriver dependency is no longer needed.